# Problem about points on an equilateral triangle

Tags: geometry, puzzle

Suppose that $A$, $B$, and $C$ are three points in a plane, such that $AB = AC = BC = 1$.
At each point in time, $A$ is moving toward $B$, $B$ is moving toward $C$, and $C$ is moving
towards $A$, all with speed $v = 50$.

At what time $T$ will all the points reach the center of the triangle?
[image]

Comment: Symmetry​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: This is Problem 1 from [link](http://catdir.loc.gov/catdir/samples/cam034/00053005.pdf). The book also gives a detailed solution to tthe same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In rotating frame of reference it is clear that points should walk $L=a\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt3}$ — it is the distance from every vertice to the point of meeting.

Because of rotating only the radial component of velocity makes sense. And it is $V=\frac{v\sqrt3}{2}$.

So, $T=\frac LV=\frac{2a}{3v}=\frac{1}{75}$.

---

OK, more formal proof.
We have three points: $A_1(R, 0),\, A_2(-R\cos\frac{2\pi}{3}, R\sin\frac{2\pi}{3}),\, A_3(R\cos\frac{4\pi}{3}, R\sin\frac{4\pi}{3})$

We will calculate the law of motion of the first point in polar coordinates $(r(t),\phi(t))$.
Initial conditions are $r(0)=R, \ \phi(0)=0$.

The second point has law of motion (due to the symmetry):  $\tilde r(t)=r(t),\ \tilde \phi(t)=\phi(t)+\alpha$, where $\alpha=\frac{2\pi}{3}$.

Generally we have $$\dfrac{\dot y}{\dot x}=\dfrac{\tilde y-y}{\tilde x-x}.$$

In polar $$\dfrac{(r\sin\phi)_t}{(r\cos\phi)_t}=\dfrac{r\sin(\phi+\alpha)-r\sin\phi}{r\cos(\phi+\alpha)-r\cos\phi}$$

From it we obtain $$\dot r+r\dot\phi\tan\frac\alpha 2=0.$$

Also points move with constant speed: $$\dot r^2+r^2\dot\phi^2=const=v^2$$

From two last equations we have $$\dot r=\pm v\sin\frac\alpha 2$$

So $$r(t)=R-vt\sin\frac\alpha 2 $$

And $$\dot\phi=\dfrac{v\cos\frac\alpha 2}{R-vt\sin\frac\alpha 2},\quad \phi(t)=-\dfrac{1}{\tan\frac\alpha 2}\ln\left(1-\dfrac{vt\sin\frac\alpha 2}{R}\right).$$

We also could obtain $r(\phi)$: $$\phi=-\dfrac{1}{\tan\frac\alpha 2}\ln\dfrac{r}{R}$$

And finally $$r(\phi)=Re^{-\phi\tan\frac\alpha 2}.$$

Time of meeting could be obtained by pointing $r(T)=0$, $T=\dfrac{R}{v\sin\frac\alpha 2}$

Comment: It's not clear to me

Comment: Supposing we have rotating frame of reference with $x$-axis along the green point and the origin at the center of triangle.
In this frame point should walk only the distance between its original position and meeting point (center). The speed is still constant but it has now only radial component. The second component is hidden in rotation of frame and it doesn't do anything useful.

Comment: I added more formal proof, if you are interested.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

- Calculate the relative velocity of $A$ to $B$ and observe that it does not change.
- Try to solve a similar question about a square. In such case use the fact, that velocity vector of $B$ is perpendicular to velocity vector of $A$, hence it does not matter – the travel time (and therefore distance too) is just as it would take to go straight to the other corner.
- In case of a triangle, adjust for the non-orthogonal vectors. The relative velocity of $A$ to $B$ is $1\cdot|v_A|+\frac{1}{2}|v_B|$ and so the time and traveled distance would be a base multiplied by $\frac{2}{3}$.

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Comment: How to observe(prove) that it does not change ?